# PHP foreach loop returns an extra unwanted array (Wikipedia API)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, wikipedia-api

I've been researching this all day and haven't found any solutions. I'm also very new to php.

The purpose of my function is to take user input (Category1) of a Wikipedia article and return its categories. The basic function below does this without any problems.

```
function get_all_categories ( ) {

        $url = $this->get_url ( 'categories' ) ;
        $url .= 'titles='.urlencode($_POST['Category1']);
        $url .= '&cllimit=500' ;        
        $data = $this->get_result ( $url ) ;

        $array = json_decode($data, true); }
```

Example result for **Urban planning**:

```
Array
(
[batchcomplete] => 
[query] => Array
    (
        [pages] => Array
            (
                [46212943] => Array
                    (
                        [pageid] => 46212943
                        [ns] => 0
                        [title] => Urban planning
                        [categories] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:All Wikipedia articles written in American English
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:Commons category with local link same as on Wikidata
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:Pages using ISBN magic links
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:Urban planning
                                    )

                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:Use American English from April 2015
                                    )

                                [5] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:Use dmy dates from April 2015
                                    )

                                [6] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:Wikipedia articles needing clarification from June 2015
                                    )

                                [7] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ns] => 14
                                        [title] => Category:Wikipedia articles with GND identifiers
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

My problem begins when I try to extract from this array only the title values. I've attempted to do this with a foreach loop which is the easiest solution I found for multidimensional arrays:

```
$array1 = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) && $key == 'categories') {
                $result = array_map(function($element){return $element['title'];}, $value);

                print_r($result);
                }               
        }
```

What I get with this code are two arrays. One array with only the titles (what I wanted), but also an unwanted array (sometime includes the first title) attached to the end:

```
Array
(
[0] => Category:All Wikipedia articles written in American English
[1] => Category:Commons category with local link same as on Wikidata
[2] => Category:Pages using ISBN magic links
[3] => Category:Urban planning
[4] => Category:Use American English from April 2015
[5] => Category:Use dmy dates from April 2015
[6] => Category:Wikipedia articles needing clarification from June 2015
[7] => Category:Wikipedia articles with GND identifiers
)
Array
(
[ns] => 
[title] => C
)
```

This extra array is what I don't understand. I think the problem is caused by the foreach loop. I tried unsetting $variable outside of the loop but it didn't help. The extra array becomes especially troublesome if I try to pass these results to another function. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity you can traverse array manually rather than using `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

`RecursiveIteratorIterator` will [kill performance](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php#112713) for large arrays.

Change your extracting logic to this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr['batchcomplete']['query']['pages'] as $k => $v)
{
    foreach($v['categories'] as $cat)
    {
        $result[] = $cat['title'];
    }
}
```

*[Working Demo](https://eval.in/709842)*

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @samir mentions, it would be faster to do it manually, but if you require a searching mechanism that traverses unknown depth, you can also use a basic recursive function. It might be a little faster than an OOP-style RecursiveArrayIterator/RecursiveIteratorIterator:

```
function recurse($array,&$new)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if($key == 'title' && isset($array['ns'])) {
                if(!isset($array['pageid']))
                    $new[]  =   $value;
            }
            else {
                if(is_array($value)) {
                    recurse($value,$new);
                }
            }
        }
    }

# Set's storage array for final titles
$new    =   array();
# Recurse your array
recurse($array,$new);
# Show stored values
print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting combination of PHP misfeatures:

- `$key == 'categories'` is non-type-safe comparison; numeric array keys are integers, and for comparing an integer with a string PHP casts the string to an integer: roughly, it takes the longest prefix of the string which consists of numbers. If the string does not start with numbers at all, the result of the string to integer conversion is `0`.
  So your condition will be true twice: for the `categories` subarray and for its first child (the one with the key `0`). Tip: always use `===` for comparison.
- PHP allows using the `[]` (array index) operator on almost anything that's not an array (usually returning null). So when the `array_map` tries to get `$element['title']` for `$element = 14` (the `ns` item of the first child of the `categories` subarray), that will succeed and result in null (which `var_dump` just displays as emptiness).
- strings are slightly different: `'foo'[$n]` is valid legacy syntax for getting the `$n`-th character of the string. When the array index operator is used on a string with a non-integer index, the index is cast to an integer (and as we have seen that usually results in zero). So `'Category:...'['title']` will result in the string  `'C'`.
  You should always be distrustful when using array index syntax on arrays with an unknown or unreliable structure, and use `isset` or something similar to make sure the array field you are trying to get exists.